# C# run screensaver preview behind moving text (like bouncing ball)

Tags: c#, gdi+, screensaver

From [[^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737408/how-does-one-run-screensaver-within-windows-form-as-background-for-it)], 
I derived the following code:

```
// *********************************** show_bubble_scr_preview

[ DllImport ( "user32.dll" ) ]
static extern IntPtr SetParent ( IntPtr clild_window_handle, 
                                 IntPtr parent_window_handle );

[ DllImport ( "user32.dll" ) ]
static extern bool MoveWindow ( IntPtr  window_handle, 
                                int     x, 
                                int     y, 
                                int     width, 
                                int     height, 
                                bool    repaint );

public static void show_bubble_scr_preview ( Control control )
{
    string  path = @"C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr";

    if ( File.Exists ( path ) )
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr  window_handle;
            Process process = new Process ( );

            process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/P " + control.Handle;

            process.Start();

            window_handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
            process.WaitForInputIdle ( );

            if ( window_handle != IntPtr.Zero )
            {
                Rectangle client_rectangle = control.
                ClientRectangle;

                SetParent ( window_handle, control.Handle );
                MoveWindow ( window_handle, 
                             client_rectangle.Left, 
                             client_rectangle.Top, 
                             client_rectangle.Width, 
                             client_rectangle.Height, 
                             true);
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The parent form contains user-specified text that moves around the 
form. During the parent form's initialization, the following actions occur:

- `InitializeComponent();`
- `SetStyle` and `UpdateStyles`
- Form is set to full screen mode
- Form Background color is set to black
- Size of the text that will move around the screen is computed
- Initial x- and y-positions of the text are computed
- A `System.Timers.Timer` is created and started
- And finally `show_bubble_scr_preview(this)` is invoked

The timer event handler is:

```
// ****************************************************** tick

void tick ( object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
{
    try
    {
        if ( this.InvokeRequired )
        {
            this.Invoke ( 
                new EventHandler ( 
                    delegate
                    {
                        this.Refresh ( );
                    } 
                ) 
            );
        }
        else
        {
            this.Refresh ( );
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {

    }
}
```

It is within `OnPaint` that the text is repositioned and redrawn.

What I was trying to achieve was to have the Bubbles.scr images float 
around the form as the text was moving. What I get is, very briefly, 
the Bubbles.scr images appear, and then the full-screen black form 
appears. The text moves as expected. But there are no bubbles. The 
`process.MainWindowHandle` is always zero.

I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I'm just guessing that maybe the screensaver is showing up behind the Form. What happens if you don't full screen it?

Comment: @jszigeti, Unfortunately if the form is not maximized, it just appears as a small form at the upper left of the monitor. Thanks for the try.